# How to split a string before the delimiter?

Tags: regex, r

I have a character string like the below.

```
a <- "T,2016,07,T,2016,07,22,T,2016,07"
```

I would like to split it to get this,

```
b <- c("T,2016,07", "T,2016,07", "T,2016,07")
```

Could you tell me the way? Many thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or use regular expression to split:

```
strsplit(a, ",(?=T)", perl = T)
# [[1]]
# [1] "T,2016,07"    "T,2016,07,22" "T,2016,07"
```

Comment: This, though I would highly suggest using stringr's str_split for faster results: `stringr::str_split(a,",(?=T)")`

Comment: Using the original `a` as well as `a <- replicate(100, paste(rep("T,2016,07,22", 1000), collapse = ","))`, the `stringr` call takes ~1/3 the execution time.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
x <- gsub("T", "%T", a)
y <- unlist(strsplit(x, "%"))[-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a <- "T,2016,07,T,2016,07,22,T,2016,07"
paste0("T", Filter(nzchar, strsplit(a, ",?T")[[1]]))
# [1] "T,2016,07"    "T,2016,07,22" "T,2016,07"
```